# Ajax post method not returning Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a VIEW, which contains a dataTable and jquery code which enables the dataTable rows to be clickable so that the user can click on a row and an ajax call is made to the server to fetch the detail of that row.

I've manage to make the dataTable row clickable, and called the Ajax function which under debug mode, I can see the POST method is being called. However, the Partial View which the returned by the POST method does not show up on my browser, even though I can see that my code is being called every step in debug mode..

My ajax/jquery is this (ive got this in a VIEW)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#dTable tbody tr').on('hover', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
    }).on('click', function () {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/TR/AllTHeaderTR",
                        data: { tID: $.trim($(this).find('td:first').text()) },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#dtable').html(data);
                            $(self).off('click');
                        }
                    });
    });
</script>
```

I can see that when clicked, the code does move through the POST method, /TR/AllTHeaderTR, which ends up doing a : return PartialView("_AllTDetailTR", travlist);

Ive also tried to replace the above with just a normal HTML page with hard coded text, but the page does not render.
Im not clued up on jquery or ajax, so could someone please assist.

Thanks
Naren

Comment: Can you trace the request's response in your client application? There is usually an error code there.

Comment: How do I go about doing that ? IE doesn't give you any error messages. But I used Firefox now and I see an error: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: You have something wrong on the server side. Look into the HTML itself, it will either say something like, "oops something went wrong" or (if you have debugging on and remoteonly error configured) the partial view html will have the error itself embedded. Also, it wouldn't hurt to check the error log.

Comment: How can I check these errors on browsers? Ive checked on developer tools and error options on Firefox, but nothing comes up .. Is there a specific place I can check ? If there is, then let me know exactly where I can find it .. thanks again

Comment: Yes, the network tab. You should see an option to start capture traffic and watch the request sent and when you get the 500 response double click the response message or some option that shows you the payload.

Comment: Ok, Ive managed to get this going, however, I do not see any errors. I have actually changed the code in my partial view to just have one line of content with html tags .. But even that is not working ...The page is not rendering

Comment: You have to have some response from the server else you are timing out and I am afraid that is not a 500.

Comment: Do you have a tool like soapui, fiddler or wire shark?

Comment: Ok, its not error 500 .. Foirefox showed it as 500 .. No, I don't have fiddler or any of the above .. Do u suggest I get that ?

Comment: If you are seeing 500 in ff then you have a response sitting there on the network tab. On the right hand side, when looking at 500, look for headers/response/request tabs. If you select the response detail and expand the body you will see more detail.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, my network went down .. Ok, I will try that .. But as far as I remember, last night, on FF, when I clicked on the detail, I could not see any error message detailing the error